# How to retrieve sixth record from database in rails using Where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to retrieve sixth, seventh and eighth record from database using ruby on rails, but it's possible only till fifth, after that undefined method sixth is coming. Please suggest me if there is any possible way.
Following is my code which I tried:

```
@reporting_masters_travel_requests4 = ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(travel_request_id: @travel_request.id,status: nil).fifth
```

Comment: Will you please provide me some example for what you said.

Comment: added code example in answer and removed comment to remove duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using where to get records from database and it returns array of objects so you can use something like this:

```
@reporting_masters_travel_requests4 = ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(travel_request_id: @travel_request.id,status: nil)[5]
```

Comment: Thank you,your query worked,i have an another query,may i ask another query if you are free???? :)

Comment: For a particular id,i want to check whether next record is present in database and based on it i need to perform operation.For example if there are 5 records present in database for foreign key 16.I want the request to be gone to first after that second and so on.If records finishes then it should prompt some flash message.

Comment: means  if fith record is present then there must be some action that will execute,if it is not present then it must generate an flash message that,record not present so request not sent.

Comment: will you please let know how may i achieve this functionality.

Comment: You can retrieve all records with foreign key (say 16) and loop on that array of objects  and perform your action in loop on loop completion you can give any message, whatever you want.

Comment: Will u please provide me explanation with an example.I'm new to rails,that is why will you provide me an example for this.I have achieve the above functionality but with the help of if and elsif but i want to achieve this with loop as what you said.So will you provide me an example.

Comment: i only want to check whether for a particular foreign key record are present @reporting_masters_travel_requests 4. If not i should get flash message.

Comment: but i want to do this with an array as you said above.

Comment: but with the help of [4],[5] as you said above.The problem with this is  not dynamic as i need to manually write this for how many time i need to check this.I need to do this dynamically means it should detect all the records automatically and generate flash messages when no record exist for that foreign key.

Comment: will u please let me know. @sandesh

Comment: by providing an example.

Comment: i'm only having confusion on applying loop on an Array and letting the loop exit with flash message which i specify.

Comment: `@reporting_masters_travel_requests = ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(travel_request_id: @travel_request.id,status: nil)` here @reporting_masters_travel_requests will be an array of objects. On which you can iterate using each method [documented here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)

Comment: @reporting_masters_travel_requests1 = ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(travel_request_id: 22,status: nil)

Comment: @reporting_masters_travel_requests1.each do |a|   end

Comment: I have done using above way....but how may i compare this and check whether record exist for a particular id or not  and generate flash message based on it.

Comment: what condition may i apply before an end to check whether record exist or not and if 1st record exist we should update the status column to true and do this process until all the record complete.But only one by one and if record does not exit it must generate an flash message.

Comment: please let me know @sandesh by providing an example.

Comment: and how may i increase my reputation because i'm unable to ask questions??

Comment: I was busy with some work and won't be able to provide you solution, can you please explain your problem some more.

Comment: Also to increase your reputation you need to answer over various questions.

Comment: i want to apply a loop on array and it must automatically exit when no record is present in database for a particular foreign key by prompting some flash message.

Comment: @Mahesh, Need some more clear view for your problem. on the above statement I have already shared the solution how to loop an array and you can exit after setting some message into the array if particular condition does not match, [HERE](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html) is documentation for array in ruby, please go through it, I think it will help you

Comment: Thanx...but will you please provide an example.

Comment: i want to check the records in a particular table with foreign key id 7.If 5 records are present the loop should automatically exit after 5 records and give flash mesaage.The table which i am using is reporting_master_travel_request.And for each record for eg 1st record it must perform some update operation.

Comment: so please  help me.

Comment: Please reply...it's really urgent for...I want that if 5 records are present for particular foreign key the loop must only iterate at that time.There must me an count function which I'll apply on where query.So it will check first record and update the status column to true and next it will find another record and return status column to true,this will continue until all records are fetched and will exit the loop by promoting flash message that record not present.

Comment: .So please help me to do this with array and count function which will let the loop exit once the last record is fetched and it's status column is updated to true after that flash message should come that record not present.so please provide me an example for this.

Answer (score 1):

```html
if @reporting_masters_travel_requests2 = ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(travel_request_id: @travel_request.id,status: nil)[1]
      ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(reporting_master_id: @reporting_masters_travel_requests2.reporting_master_id).update_all(status: "true",daily_bill_comment: @comment)

TravelRequest.where(id: @travel_request.id).update_all(reporting_master_id: @reporting_masters_travel_requests3.reporting_master_id)
      flash[:notice] = 'Daily Bill Request Send To Higher Authority For Approval'
     
elsif @reporting_masters_travel_requests3 = ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(travel_request_id: @travel_request.id,status: nil)[2]
      ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(reporting_master_id: @reporting_masters_travel_requests3.reporting_master_id).update_all(status: "true",daily_bill_comment: @comment)
      TravelRequest.where(id: @travel_request.id).update_all(reporting_master_id: @reporting_masters_travel_requests4.reporting_master_id)
      flash[:notice] = 'Daily Bill Request Send To Higher Authority For Approval'

elsif @reporting_masters_travel_requests4 = ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(travel_request_id: @travel_request.id,status: nil)[3]
      ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(reporting_master_id: @reporting_masters_travel_requests4.reporting_master_id).update_all(status: "true",daily_bill_comment: @comment)
      TravelRequest.where(id: @travel_request.id).update_all(reporting_master_id: @reporting_masters_travel_requests5.reporting_master_id)
      flash[:notice] = 'Daily Bill Request Send To Higher Authority For Approval'

 else
   flash[:alert] = 'No Reporting Manager is present'
end
```

I have used the above code and it works perfectly,but its not so dynamic as i manually need to specify for how many time if want to check in table via array [4].But problem is what if 10 records are present in database then for this the above logic will fail.

Comment: @sandesh pls reply im waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
@reporting_masters_travel_requests = ReportingMastersTravelRequest.where(travel_request_id: @travel_request.id,status: nil)

@reporting_masters_travel_requests.each do |record|
  #Something like record.update record.save
end
#set a msg like no more records after loop
msg="No more records"
```

Comment: the above logic is perfect but in want to check first record,if it is present then   status column should be updated to true,now employee with id 77 will log into his account and click on approve button,after that the status column of that employee should update to true.This process must continue untill all the records for employee has status updated to true,it will go on checking untill all records for that foreign key updated to true and only the employee with specific id in the table can Click on approve and perform update operation on status.

Comment: i have done the above process with the help of if and elsif but its not dynamic,so i want this to be done using loop.

Comment: I tried The above methods but it updates all the records belonging to that foreign key are update and due to this all my status updates to true.It must be done one by one,means if first record status is nil and it has employee id say 77,the employee will login to his account and perform approve operation,and then that specific record belonging to that employee will be updated to true.This all will be done one by one.

Comment: i have attached an screenshot,kindly refer above,so you will clearly get what i want...@sandesh

Comment: if employee does no log in to his account then its status column for particular foreign key may not be updated to true until and unless he log into his account and perform action on Approve button.

Comment: So basically you want to create some sort of UI that empowers user to approve travel status. So you just need to fetch records related to that user and display them when they update that particular UI you need to update that record.

Comment: yaa...i only wants the user to approve request and on approving the request  it must update the status column of that particular id to true and basically all my ui is ready,i nly want the status column to updated to true whenever user perform some action.But problem is only that it must automatically flash some message that record not present when all the status column of that particular foreign key is updated to true.

Comment: U only let me know the basic syntax which i may i use,coz the above solution which you specified updates all the record at once,i only want it to be updated one by one,not all at once and should flash message when records for that id is updated to true and no record is present.

Comment: i have used if and elsif statement for this purpose,but its not dyanamic.